# Batch Commit for Inserting users in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

We are trying to insert about 100k users in Liferay. Is there a way to have this all updated in one batch commit, instead of making separate calls to add each user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It think yes it's possible.

Build a custom remote service entity like `BulkUserServiceUtil.addUsers`, within it call the standard method `UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser` for each user.

Returning from the `BulkUserServiceUtil` method the transaction is committed.

Comment: +1 for going the service way. *Do not* use SQL inserts: Don't *ever* write to the database using SQL, because Liferay needs more than just what's obvious in the user table. This warning is missing, otherwise I'd fully support this answer.

Answer (score -3):

@sandeep:

Yes, Liferay not provide us to add/update bulk users, because after user creation some table affected in that and also user indexed, but if you want to do that I have two suggestions :

1. **Take a reference of REINDEX option of articles**: in that case you can create a batch of counter range with some sort of value and update/add that batch, but the thing is Liferay internally call addUser default. So its iterative way which you can use.
2. **Without Service** : Create some custom script and directly hit the DB for once. which create users but in that case you have to take care of other liferay tables which need to be insert the userID or respective data.

Comment: Sorry but "Create some custom script and directly hit the DB for once" is possible but it is a very bad habit for liferay.

Comment: calling 100k times iteration best you can write some sort code which not  hitting DB that much. If Liferay not allow then we've to do something different.